# Showing website elements in WebView

Tags: javascript, android, browser, webview

So first off, I have no clue how AndroidStudio works or how to code anything other than the stuff I've learned in school so far.
The only reason I want to write this app is to gain some experience and learn a bit as well as help a bit in school.
I want my app to go to a specific website, but only show one element that can be found in the website's source code. I can not edit the website itself as it is not mine.
 I took a few tutorials and bodged my way through, however I've only come as far as to have the app visit the website, which is a little bit redundant since in that case chrome will do as well.
This is my code for the main activity java class so far:

```
private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    // Enable Javascript
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MainActivity(), "HTMLOUT");
    android:mWebView.loadUrl("*link*");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(){

        public void onPagefinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            android:mWebView.loadUrl("*link*");

        }
    });
    android:mWebView.loadUrl("*link*");
```

So assuming the element in the source code is called "leftplan", how would I make only that element show up in the app?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is download the web page as html. Then parse it and copy the parts that you want into an `String` or another Html file. Then use web view to show the content of that.

For downloading and parsing you can use `jsoup` It's and java library for working with html content and it's amazing!

Comment: Thanks, I will see what I can bodge together with that knowledge :)